# How to react to LVN_ITEMCHANGED notification only when user finishes selecting action on multipe selection CListCtrl?

Tags: c++, multi-select, selectionchanged, multipleselection, clistctrl

I have a dialog with two list controls and one custom control with some graphic preview.

The first has a list of one kind of entities (1a, 1b, 1c,...) and the second has a list of another kind of entites (2a, 2b, 2c,...), both of them are multi-select.

I want to allow user to select a set of entities that will be highlighted on preview, but only those from a list where the last selection has been made.

For example:

1. select 1a,1b,1c -> **highlight** them on preview
2. select 2a,2b,2c -> **unhighlight** 1a,1b,1c and **highlight** 2a,2b,2c

If I process each `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` notification, the preview will be flickering, so I want to paint the preview when user finishes selection with a function like this:

```
void CPreviewPage::PaintSelection(HWND hWnd)
{
  m_preview.DeselectAll();
  SelectArray select;
  if(hWnd == m_lstFirst.GetSafeHwnd())
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < m_lstFirst.GetItemCount(); i++)
    {
      if( m_lstFirst.GetItemState(i, LVNI_SELECTED) & LVNI_SELECTED)
      {
        Entity *pEnt = (Entity *) m_lstFirst.GetItemData(i);
        select.append(pEnt);
      }
    }
  }
  else
  if(hWnd == m_lstSecond.GetSafeHwnd())
  {
    for( int i = 0; i < m_lstSecond.GetItemCount(); i++ )
    {
      if( m_lstSecond.GetItemState(i, LVNI_SELECTED) & LVNI_SELECTED)
      {
        Entity *pEnt = (Entity *) m_lstSecond.GetItemData(i);
        select.append(pEnt);
      }
    }
  }
  m_preview.PaintSelect(&select);
}
```

The problem is; when I have 2a selected, then hold shift and click 2c (to select 2a-2c), I get multiple `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` and can't detect which of them is last. If I could, then it would be possible to repaint the preview at the right moment, which is when the user finishes his/her selecting action.

I tried to call the repaint function when I get `LVNI_FOCUSED`:

```
void CPreviewPage::OnLstSecondSelChanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
  NM_LISTVIEW* pNMListView = (NM_LISTVIEW*) pNMHDR;

  if((pNMListView->uChanged & LVIF_STATE) && (pNMListView->uNewState & LVNI_FOCUSED) )
    PaintSelection(pNMHDR->hwndFrom);
}
```

However, the `LVNI_FOCUSED` isn't guaranteed to be the last, and I don't want to add a button to call `PaintSelection` function.

So the question is: when is the right moment when I will have the state of all items set, according to user selection so I can call `PaintSelection`?

Comment: You could use a timer to decide the moment you can start previewing. You don't handle the `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` individually, but when a notification comes you reset the timer and put the notification in a list. When the timer elapses you handle the list of notifications you received that far. Maybe the timeout could be half a second. So users would be able to do some selection, and half a second after they stop you paint the preview.

Comment: Thanks, Marius. Using timer works like a charm :)

Comment: I was using `ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, IDC_LIST_CTRL, OnItemchangedListCtrl)` for handling a list control's selection . But there was a case it was not behaving the way I expected:  when the item was already selected, and the user clicks that item again, I wanted an action to occur even knowing the select item was the same. For achieving my goal, I had to also handle `ON_NOTIFY(NM_CLICK, IDC_LIST_CTRL, OnNMClickListCtrl)` for the specific case.